# Import PowerQuery .odc file to other workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I want to import .odc file (Power Query) to an excel file to create a report.

I recorded the process with Record Macro on excel.
I got the code below, but when I run it, an error occurs:

**Application-defined or object-defined error**

The code below is highlighted.

`.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False`

```
    Sub ImportDataConnection()
'
' ImportDataConnection Macro
'

'
Windows("aExcelFile.xlsx").Activate
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
    "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Table1;Extended Properties=""""" _
    , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Table1]")
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .SourceConnectionFile = _
    "C:\Users\SomeUser\Documents\My Data Sources\Query - Table1.odc"
    .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_Query___Table1"
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With

End Sub
```

After running the code above, the connection shows up in the Queries & Connections pane, but the query does not exist in the pane.

[image]

When recording, I imported the odc file by clicking Existing Connections and then selected the odc file. When I do that manually the query was also imported.

[image]

[image]

What is the best practice to import power query??
How do I solve this error?

Comment: Did the macro not record an `ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add` statement ?

Comment: No. I don't see the statement. Where should it be placed?

Comment: Is the code shown the complete recorded macro ?

Comment: @CDP1802 I added the extra codes that was also recorded, but this is it. When I do the importing process manually, the query was also imported. Please see the post. I updated it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the connection first then the table.

```vb
    Const USERNAME = "SomeUser"
    Const CON = "Query - Table1"
    
    Dim DataSrc As String
    DataSrc = "C:\Users\" & USERNAME & "\Documents\My Data Sources\" & CON & ".odc"
    
    With ThisWorkbook
        .Connections.AddFromFile DataSrc, True, False
    End With
    
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=4, Source:=ActiveWorkbook. _
        Connections(CON), Destination:=Range("$A$1")).TableObject
        .RowNumbers = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshStyle = 1
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table1"
        .Refresh
    End With
```